# How do i find out which GWT element has focus?

Tags: javascript, jquery, gwt

I would like to find out, in GWT, which element currently has focus. Basically i was working on virtual keyboard in our application. All keys are working fine except tab key. If i get focused element then i can work out the tab key code.

In javascript and jquery we can get this using `document.activeElement`. Hope some body will put me in right way to achieve this.

Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 7):

The fact that it's not supported in "all browsers" is only important if your app is targeting all browsers. activeElement is currently supported by quite a few browsers [Why is there no isFocused() in GWT?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7394297/why-is-there-no-isfocused-in-gwt).

I needed something similar, I needed to know from inside a widget if it had focus.  I did the following

```
protected native boolean hasFocus(Element element) /*-{
   return element.ownerDocument.activeElement == element;
}-*/;
```

I needed to pass in the current element to get the proper document, just calling

```
document.activeElement;
```

did not give me the document I needed.  You could likely do the same but pass in the a different element (RootPanel element maybe?) and return the in focus Element rather than a bool.

```
protected native Element elementInFocus(Element element) /*-{
   return element.ownerDocument.activeElement;
}-*/;
```

Comment: You should use "$doc" instead of "document" in JSNI. Same goes for $wnd instead of "window".

Answer (score 1):

`document.activeElement` doesn't work in all browsers so there's no support for that in GWT. You could maybe use focus&blur handlers to keep track which element has it.

Comment: ok.Thanks for your reply.If you have any sample can you share about focushandlers to get active element?

Comment: oh its ok but if you find any solution please share with us.we will also try a max to find out solution in less time :-).Thanks for your guidance.

Comment: sure. try with focus & blur handlers, it doesn't seem that difficult. all you need to do is to maintain a currently selected element in a variable (set on focus, reset on blur).

Comment: @Matrix Hope the example code is useful for others, as it seems it's too late for you.

Answer (score 1):

Short template:

```
public class IntBox extends com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.IntegerBox {

private boolean focused=false;

public IntBox(){

        addFocusHandler(new FocusHandler() {

            @Override
            public void onFocus(FocusEvent event) {
                focused=true;
            }
        });

        addBlurHandler(new BlurHandler() {

            @Override
            public void onBlur(BlurEvent event) {
                focused=false;
            }
        });

    }

    public boolean isFocused() {
        return focused;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

We can now use the Elemental library to accomplish this.

http://www.gwtproject.org/articles/elemental.html

the exact function would be

```
elemental.client.Browser.getDocument().getActiveElement()
```