# Issue with changing the font color of one text area in gxt

Tags: java, html, css, gwt, gxt

I have multiple text areas in a container. I need to change the font color of one particular text area that has been focused recently. How to determine that ? In the below code, I am able to change the font color of all the text areas.

```
  @Override
  public void onValueChange(ValueChangeEvent<String> event) {
     fontColorMenu.hide();
     for(int i=0; i< flowLayoutContainer.getWidgetCount(); i++){
        Widget widget = flowLayoutContainer.getWidget(i);
            if(widget instanceof TextArea){
                TextArea textArea = (TextArea) widget;
                StyleInjector.inject(".textAreaFontColor > div > textarea {color: #"+event.getValue()+" !important;} ");
                textArea.setStyleName("textAreaFontColor", true);
            }
     }
}
```

Comment: Take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8939571/how-do-i-find-out-which-gwt-element-has-focus. This might help.