# Gwt check if object has focus

Tags: java, gwt, focus

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why is there no isFocused() in GWT?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7394297/why-is-there-no-isfocused-in-gwt)

Hi guys is possible check if a specific object has focus ? My problem in my web app is determine which object has focus when i press tab button, for each focus i need to do a specific action. thx

Comment: JavaScript contains a _focus_ event. You should look into how GWT provides access to that. [Description of the event](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onfocus.asp).

Comment: Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8939571/how-do-i-find-out-which-gwt-element-has-focus

Comment: Please use the stackvoverflow search!!!!

Answer (score -3):

This is already addressed here - [Why is there no isFocused() in GWT?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7394297/why-is-there-no-isfocused-in-gwt)

Please use the stackvoverflow search!!!!

Comment: Please flag as duplicate instead of posting an answer like this.

Comment: Amused :) . Stackoverflow should retire answers. It is 4 years since the answer i posted.